# Date not changing with object.setDate()

Tags: javascript, date

I'm trying to create a calendar object with weeks, days and hours, where each day has a date. I set the starting date to Jan 2. 2017 but after the loop is completed all the days in the calendar has the date Jan 2. 2018.

```
var calendar = {};
var date = new Date(2017,0,2);

calendar['weeks'] = [];
for (var w = 0; w < 52; w++) {
    calendar['weeks'][w] = {};
    calendar['weeks'][w]['number'] = w+1; 
    calendar['weeks'][w]['days'] = [];
    for (var d = 0; d < 7; d++) {
        calendar['weeks'][w]['days'][d] = {};
        calendar['weeks'][w]['days'][d]['date'] = date;
        calendar['weeks'][w]['days'][d]['hours'] = [];
        calendar['weeks'][w]['days'][d]['number'] = d+1; 
        for (var h = 0; h < 24; h++) {
            calendar['weeks'][w]['days'][d]['hours'][h] = {};
            calendar['weeks'][w]['days'][d]['hours'][h]['number'] = h+1;
        }
        date.setDate(date.getDate()+1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that you can write `calendar.weeks` instead of `calendar['weeks']`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only have **one** `date` object. When you link it into your `calendar` object over and over again in that loop, every reference is to the same object.

You'll need to make new instances on each iteration:

```
    date = new Date(date);
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
```

Alternatively, make a new instance when you set up that "date" property:

```
    calendar['weeks'][w]['days'][d]['date'] = new Date(date);
```

which could also be written:

```
    calendar.weeks[w].days[d].date = new Date(date);
```

Comment: Since the *set\** methods return the new time value: `calendar.weeks[w].days[d].date = new Date(date.setDate(date.getDate()+1))` will increment and copy in one go. ;-)